# What is going wrong in this perl substitution?

Tags: regex, perl

```
my $test = "_.4.1\n";
print $test;
my $docid=4;
$test =~ s/_.$docId.1/_.$docId.0/gm;
print $test
```

I was hoping to see:

_.4.1

_.4.0

But I get:

_.4.1

_.4.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a capital `I` in `$docId` in your regex, but declare it with a lower case `i`. `$docid` is not considered the same variable as `$docId`. Perl differentiates between upper and lower case inside variable names.

You should always use

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

To prevent simple errors like this.

See also: [Why use strict and warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings)

Comment: As a simple habbit, I always use perl -w

Comment: Why would you use `-w`, when the more flexible and powerful alternative, `use warnings` was added to Perl over ten years ago?

Comment: Because it is very simple to always set -w even on a -e oneliner.

Comment: @Nikodemus: Agreed. I wish there was an switch for `use strict` too, so I could avoid `perl -Mstrict -we '...'`.

Comment: It's not do one or do the other. "use warning" is good style. But sometimes you need to test a thing on don't know where the problem is. -w is a quick way to get additional information.

Comment: @Nikodemus For one-liners, `-w` is often perfectly fine. @flesk `-M5.012` activates strict, saving a whopping 2 characters. Or in *nix, make an alias `p perl -Mstrict -wE` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Perl 5.10 has a nice feature that makes this problem easier. a `\K` in the pattern portion of the substitution operator tells it to not replace anything before the `\K`. That way, you can make the pattern to locate the bit that you want to change, but then only replace the part that doesn't change:

```
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $test = "_.4.1";
say $test;

my $docId=4;
$test =~ s/_\.$docId\.\K1/0/;

say $test;
```

I removed the `/g` and `/m` flags because they don't do anything in your example.

If you aren't using v5.10 yet (and it's one of the unsupported versions now), you can get the same effect with a positive lookbehind (as long as it's a constant width pattern):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $test = "_.4.1";
print "$test\n";

my $docId = 4;
$test =~ s/(?<=_\.$docId\.)1/0/;

print "$test\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the -w option in perl

```
_.4.1
Use of uninitialized value $docId in regexp compilation at test.pl line 4.
_.4.1


$docid != $docId;
```

Comment: Before you recommend the global `-w` switch over the lexical `warnings` pragma next time, learn the difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221919/should-i-turn-on-perl-warnings-with-the-command-line-switch-or-pragma